# Understanding tensorboard images

Tags: keras, tensorboard

I want to use keras+tensorboard. My architecture looks like this:

```
tbCallBack = TensorBoard(log_dir='./logs', histogram_freq=2, batch_size=32, write_graph=True, write_grads=True, write_images=True)

K.clear_session()
sess = tf.Session()
K.set_session(sess)

input_img = Input(shape=(augmented_train_data[0].shape[0], augmented_train_data[0].shape[1], 3))

x = Conv2D(8, (1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu', name="1x1_1")(input_img)
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', name="3x3_1")(x)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', name="3x3_2")(x)
x = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu', name="1x1_2")(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(16, activation='relu')(x)


output = Dense(2)(x)

model = Model(inputs=input_img, outputs=output)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

#tbCallBack.set_model(model)
print(model.summary())

history = model.fit(augmented_train_data, augmented_train_label, validation_data=[augmented_validation_data, augmented_validation_label] ,epochs=20, batch_size=32, callbacks=[tbCallBack])
```

When looking at the tensorboard image tab, it looks like this[image]
I cant quite interpret that though, I thought this tab would show how the weights of my convolutions develop over the epochs. So, how to interpret these images. Or did I do a mistake in setting up tensorboard?

Comment: Have you figured out what's going on? I asked about this in here before as well but no one replied either.

Comment: Unfortuantely not

Comment: If you still have the log directory, could you upload it to [Aughie Boards](https://boards.aughie.org/)? It would be easier to answer if I could inspect the images through the interactive dashboard

Comment: unfortuantely i dont have them anymore

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that is exactly what you are getting. The grayscale of the image shows the weights. The slider on top can be used to go back and forth in epochs and hence look at the training progression.

Comment: But why are there only three biases (I would have expected eight, one for each convolution), and why are the fields of the biases so much bigger?

Comment: one per channel

Comment: But shouldnt there still be 8 times 3 then, for each kernel 3 biases?

Comment: Conv 2D should have one per channel. In the definition of Conv2D in the Keras source they define one bias per channel

Comment: The Conv2D [source](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/convolutional.py#L139). So the 3 elements you see there could be the bias for one of the filters. If you are willing to share your TB logdir i can take a further look, now everything i say is just based on conclusions made by looking at a static screenshot. Also, this is not just a question of how Tensorboard translates data but also how Keras writes the images. And this is version specific. So you should include the Keras and TB versions you are using for reproducibility and source code reference.